# KENDO UI ANGULAR inspect STYLES of POPUP element in CHROME

Tags: google-chrome, kendo-ui, popup, styles, inspect

Consider a situation when you have for example KENDO Angular UI component... for example plain dropdown.

When you click on dropdown it will show you its menu. Now you want to inspect styles of this menu or styles of one of many items in this menu.

So you will do right-click > inspect... and?

And nothing, because you did left-click to confirm your order and dropdown menu have disappeared so you will not see anything in developer tools.

The second thing is you can't find any js script which triggers this dropdown menu opening.

The third thing is you can use developer tools function ctrl + shift + c so you can see at least some classes, but you cant see styles itself.

Is there any other option how to inspect this instantly-disappearing windows?

thank you very much :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Temporarily prevent the [close event](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui-develop/components/dropdowns/api/DropDownListComponent/#toc-close):

[EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sur5rg?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
<div class="example-wrapper">
  <p>T-shirt size:</p>
  <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="listItems" (close)="$event.preventDefault()">
  </kendo-dropdownlist>
</div>
```

Comment: MAN... you are awesome !!!!! you saved me many hours of suffering... last entire week I tried to guess kendo classes :)

Answer (score 5):

the easiest way to inspect kendo popup is to turn on **Event listener breakpoints** in dev tools. Open your developer tool in Chrome (F12) navigate to **Sources** tab and enable **Mouse events**. It will stack on your every click. You'll be able to inspect kendo popup

See screenshot:

[image: Chrome developer tools screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

answer is: 
you can force your kendo angular component to be opened to inspect it:

catch your dropdown via @ViewChild/Content and add following row

this.dropdownlist.toggle(true);